# PHP issue: unable to print row numbers white looping through associative array

Tags: php, foreach

I am doing a basic XML parsing operation with the help of PHP `simplexml_load_file`.

I looped through a "CD catalog" and printed out song-name, artist etc, in an HTML table. To my supersize, given the structure of the info in the XML file, I was unable to print *row numbers*.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
  $catalog = simplexml_load_file('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml');
  $cds = $catalog->CD;
?>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th class="text-left">Song</th>
      <th class="text-left">Artist</th>
      <th class="text-left">Year</th>
      <th class="text-left">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($cds as $k=>$cd) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $k; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $cd->TITLE; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $cd->ARTIST; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $cd->YEAR; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $cd->PRICE; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The first column prints "CD" instead of the row number.

What shall I change to print row numbers?

Comment: What does the array look like? Why not just add a counter and increase on each iteration? If it prints "CD" on each iteration then there must be some wrong with the array since all keys are named "CD"

Comment: @andreas `$catalog` is not an array. It's a SimpleXML object that implements the `Iterable` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is a simple solution just cast your xml object as string into a new array and loop it :

```
<?php
$catalog = simplexml_load_file('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml');
$cds = $catalog->CD;
$customCatalog = array();
foreach ($cds as  $value) {
    $temp = array(
        'TITLE' =>$value->TITLE->__toString() ,
        'ARTIST'=> $value->ARTIST->__toString(),
        'COUNTRY'=>$value->COUNTRY->__toString(),
        'COMPANY'=>$value->COMPANY->__toString(),
        'PRICE'=>$value->PRICE->__toString(),
        'YEAR'=>$value->YEAR->__toString()
    );
    $customCatalog [] = $temp;
}

//print_r($customCatalog);

foreach ($customCatalog as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value)) {
        echo $key;
        echo $value["TITLE"];
        echo $value["ARTIST"];
        echo $value["COUNTRY"];
        echo $value["COMPANY"];
        echo $value["PRICE"];
        echo $value["YEAR"];
    }
}
?>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Andreas, I made a `$rowCount = 1;` and incremented it on each iteration:

```
<?php
    $catalog = simplexml_load_file('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml');
    $cds = $catalog->CD;
    $rowCount = 1;
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My favourite songs</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Songs">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel panel-default table-container">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">Great songs</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th class="text-left">Song</th>
              <th class="text-left">Artist</th>
              <th class="text-left">Year</th>
              <th class="text-left">Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($cds as $k=>$cd) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo  $rowCount++; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $cd->TITLE; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $cd->ARTIST; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $cd->YEAR; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $cd->PRICE; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is phpFiddle **[here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q4n1-c9se)**.

Still, is there a solution that involves the `$catalog` array only?

Comment: `$catalog` is not an array. It's a SimpleXML object that implements the `Iterable` interface.

Comment: Thanks for the info.